# Scipy error: numpy.flatiter size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-2.6

I am getting the following Warning when running some python scripts

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py:91: RuntimeWarning: numpy.flatiter size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from .qhull import *
```

I have noticed that others have seen similar errors when scipy is compiled against a version of numpy that is different from the runtime version. I did upgrade both numpy and scipy after having installed both, in order to get some other python libraries. Current versions are numpy 1.9.1 and scipy 0.14.0.

As suggested in other threads, I have uninstalled and reinstalled both numpy and scipy. I have also tried using `pip install --no-use-wheel`, using `easy_install`, downgrading to numpy 1.7.1, all to no avail.

Any suggestions about what to do from here?? Thanks in advance.